# Schema building with foreign keys

Tags: laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could show me how to write the following `SQL` in `Laravel 4`Schema Builder`?

```
CREATE TABLE `conversation_reply` (
`cr_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reply` text,
`user_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`c_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (c_id_fk) REFERENCES conversation(c_id)
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, this should be close;

```php
Schema::table('conversation_reply', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('cr_id');
    $table->text('reply')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id_fk')->references('user_id')->on('users');
    $table->string('ip', 30);
    $table->integer('time');
    $table->foreign('c_id_fk')->references('c_id')->on('conversation');
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for that ... One quick question .. What does the ->nullable() tag mean?

Comment: @BigJobbies It's the opposite of `NOT NULL`, so it just means that the column can be set to `NULL`.

Comment: Oh ok, So the nullable would be set if i was to have something like this-> `ip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: @BigJobbies No, that'd be `->default(NULL)`. The `->nullable()` just means the column can be set to null at all.

Comment: I would say add ->onDelete('cascade') ->onUpdate('cascade') like this: $table->foreign('user_id_fk')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade') ->onUpdate('cascade');

Answer (score 1):

Do Following:

Below Schema will go inside schema-migrations file under `public function up()`

```
//Create ** category table **

    Schema:Create ('category',function ($table)){

                //Relation: category table id used as FK -> to -> product table category_id
                $table->increments('category_id');
                //category name
                $table->string('category_name',40)->unique();
                //time staps: created,Updated
                $table->timestamps();
    }
```

Than,Inside product schema:

```
            //Create ** product table **

            Schema::create('products', function ($table){

                //product id
                $table->increments('product_id');
                //product name
                $table->string('p_name')->unique();
                //product description
                $table->text('p_description');
                //created_at and  updated_at column
                $table->timestamps();
                //Foregine Key
                $table->integer('category_id_fk')->unsigned();
                //Foreign Key link to category table
              $table->foreign('category_id_fk')->references('category_id')->on('category');
         }
```